# What do you call a person who checks emails too frequently?

Tags: word-request

I'm searching for the term (and trust me, I had read it somewhere) that refers to a person who checks emails too frequently.

It's a sort of *[obsessive compulsive disorder](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0001926/).* I want this term because I come across such people too frequently these days. After all, mails are now available on smartphones.

Comment: I don't call him, I send him an email... :-)

Comment: @Kiwy good gag. A smiley is needed though!

Comment: Sorry It was too tempting :D fact is you should read this wiki article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_addiction_disorder

Comment: How about Addict???

Comment: @Kiwy I'm a healthcare provider and know about the disorder. I'm asking for the **term** for a person! It's something like this page talks about 'epilepsy' and I'm asking for the term 'epileptic!!

Comment: @VijayaRagavan too general!

Comment: Hi, Is this possible -> "email-holic" ? (-:

Comment: Thanks,I think it's Not too bad for my first attempt at answering others :)

Comment: @GATA brilliant... wait... you nailed it. I'm answering myself for that!

Comment: The correct term is "teenager".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a ton GATA. You showed me a direction to search on the Internet.

Though not official but researchers have used the term. It is - **[emailaholic](http://www.switched.com/2009/05/12/are-you-an-emailaholic/)**.

The term was mentioned when the researchers studied the cases of people suffering from anxiety/depression as they *could not access* the Internet/mails. The anxiety even got a name - [Discomgoogolation.](http://www.switched.com/2008/09/02/e-mail-deprivation-anxiety-has-a-new-name-discomgoogolation/)

*-aholic* suffix is used with a noun.

> *-[aholic](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/aholic)*: liking something very much and unable to stop doing or using it.

Thanks again, GATA.

Comment: My pleasure :) You have answered many of my questions. I will be happy to help you in return.

Comment: @GATA Yeah! The term was too common but I just missed it. You tickled my noodle in time! I was searching for the phrase, instead, should have searched for the term. haha....

Comment: If their persistent email reading is work related, they could be called a _workaholic_.

Comment: Downvoter will you enlighten me please :)

Comment: -aholic (or -oholic) comes from the term "alcoholic".  The first such term I remember seeing is "workoholic" which morphed into "workaholic" at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Not a word specifically for checking emails, but a *Nomophobe* is someone who fears being without a smartphone.

Comment: +1 as smartphones generally have the Internet connection. Also, this is close. A person with nomophobia is *nomophobic* I guess.